# Contact form keeps sending blank emails

Tags: php, email, contacts

Here's my contact form php code. Every morning I receive a blank response from my contact form.

```
<?php 
     $to = "test@youremail.com";
     $subject = "Contact Form Inquiry"; 
     $name = $_POST['name'] ; 
     $email = $_POST['email'] ; 
     $message = $_POST['message'] ; 
     $content = "From: $name \n Message: $message";
     $headers = "From: $email "; 
     $sent = mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers) ; 
     if($sent) 
     {
        print "Your mail was sent successfully"; 
     }
     else 
     {
        print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; 
     }
 ?>
```

Why do I receive this response?

Comment: have your check your `print_r($_POST)`.  show your contact form here. are you sure you are submitting form through `post`

Comment: Check your robots.txt file for denial to the contact form page and maybe install fail2ban on your server.

Comment: It will be easier to diagnose if you give us your HTML/Javascript that is initiating this code from the browser.

Comment: Also, you should trim and check `$name`, `$email` and `$message` for blank values and deny submission if any are blank (assuming you want all to be mandatory).

Comment: Agree with the robots.txt file - search engine spiders usually trigger forms like this but I can't tell if you mean *all* form submissions are empty, or just randomly.

Comment: My guess is what Deryck said, a bot (like Google) is crawling your site and inadvertently sending a blank form that your code then sends.  You could do a check in your PHP to make sure that the $_POST[] variables are not blank before sending the email.

Comment: He said each morning he gets one

Answer (score 2):

**$_POST['message'] ;**

> Please check if this variable coming up with any value from your form.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CAPTCHA or similar alternatives, there are a lot of bots out there.
You could also generate a CSRF token (look at the Wikipedia article if you aren't sure about it), so the form will require it before actually sending the e-mail. Many frameworks do this for you.